# batch and subdivisions in YOLOv3

Tags: yolo, darknet

I'm using YOLOv3 and YOLOv3-Tiny from [AlexeyAB's fork of Darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet).  I understand that the image size must be a multiple of 32.  And that `batch` divided by `subdivisions` determines the number of images that will be processed in parallel.

For example, the batch size in the default yolov3.cfg file is `64`, and subdivision is `16`, meaning 4 images will be loaded at once, and it will take 16 of these mini batches to complete one iteration.

What I don't see documented [in the wiki](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/CFG-Parameters-in-the-%5Bnet%5D-section):

**Are there restrictions on these values?**  Do they need to be a multiple of 16?  Power of 2?  Can I have `batch=25` and `subdivisions=5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is not a must to be a power of 2, the important thing is that `batch` must be divisible by `subdivisions` as the code uses small batches of `batch / subdivisions` as you can see in **parcer.c**:

`net->batch /= subdivs;`

then the number of images processed in every step is defines as in **detector.c**:

`int imgs = net.batch * net.subdivisions * ngpus;`

Although the defined `BLOCK` in **dark_cuda.h** is 512, the used `num_blocks` in the kernels doesn't have to be divisible by 2 as can be seen in **dark_cuda.c**:

```
int get_number_of_blocks(int array_size, int block_size)
{
    return array_size / block_size + ((array_size % block_size > 0) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

I think the only problem could be a performance issue as CUDA runs in wraps of 32, so any number not a multiple of 2 may cause part of the used memory to not be fully utilized.

However, I recommend that you try training your network with these parameters to confirm that it works as desired.

Comment: The code can handle when batch is not divisible by subdivisions, for info. Not a big deal anyway!